# Stored Procedure `sp_rename` missing in my edition of SQL Server. How can I get it?

Tags: sql-server-express, visual-studio-express

I am using the Visual Studio C# Express edition and it comes with SQL Server for Database. I need the stored procedure `sp_rename` so that I can call it in my software to change specified table names.

Is there any way that I can import it from somewhere or get it by chance, because I notice that SQL Server in Visual Studio is limited and does not have the predefined stored procedure like the full version of SQL Server.

Is there any way to import certain stored procedures into my SQL Server for Visual Studio C# Express Edition?

I can run stored procedures, I just do not have the ones you usually get when you buy the complete SQL Server.

The following is my code. It will change the name of the database.

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
string renameCommand = "EXEC sp_rename 'NetworkAccount' , 'oldhires'";
SqlCommand sqlRenameCommand = new SqlCommand(renameCommand, sqlConnectionCmdString);
sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();
sqlRenameCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
```

Comment: The easier your question is to read and understand, the more likely it is that it'll receive answers. One way to achieve legibility is to use proper punctuation and sentence structure. I've edited your post this time, but strongly recommend to you that you take more care to do this yourself next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql server express contains full set of standard/basic stored procedures, including sp_rename

most likely you mistyped procedure name or have problems with permissions

Comment: Im using the SQL in the Visual Studio C# Express Edition in the folder where it says Stored Procedure there is no stored procedures in that folder

Comment: system stored procedures can be found via SSMS under master->programmability->stored procedures->system stored procedures node

Comment: I don't have a masters table cause it installed SQL Server 2008 with no clustering do you know what folder I install the clustering to in SQL Server. once I do that it will add the masters table and the predefined stored procedures...

Comment: "master" is not a table, it is a system database that is automatically created on every instance of installed sql server of any edition. anyway - why you do not simply call sp_rename procedure using, say, "sys.sp_rename"  name? i'm sure it will work.

Comment: I understand I am working out of Database Explorer not on an instance directly off the server I am trying to load the systems stored procedures in the Database Explorer I am sorry if I am confusing you on what I am trying to do ill try to see if that sys.sp_rename will work. But can I call a stored procedure in another stored procedure as well just to be sure.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR IT WORKED, I'll Display the code for you... on what I did I was confused cause you never see the stored procedures in the Database explorer as if you was looking on the SQL server it self. So I as wondering where was all the stuff you would see on the SQL Server

Comment: the best way to know - is to try :) Simply write test code which call sp_rename (even with incorrect/null parameters) - and you will see if can you find/call procedure or not.

Comment: I know but I don't even know the half of them by name, so cause I downloaded the visual studio C#, SQL server came with it but it don't define the server exactly although its there you don't see it. I need to download SQL Express so I can see what can be used through the Database Explorer or something

Comment: you can find full list and description of system stored procedures at online documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Is there any way I can use variable where it says oldhires in that code.. so I can pass the name of the table that I need if the table name changes at times..??

Comment: look at SqlParameter class and SqlCommand.Parameters property